# Selenium getText behaviour

Tags: selenium, gettext

I have an html file which has to be parsed using selenium.
I need to extract a the text contained in a `div` tag which has an unique `id`.
The original file is as follows:

```
<div id="debugState" style="display:none"> 
            Model: ModelCode[UK51]
            Features: [S08TL, S0230, S0851, S0428, S01CD, S0879, S01CA, S08SP, S0698,  S01CB, S0548, S08SC, S08TM, S04AK, S01CC, S0801]
            Packages: [S0801]
</div>
```

The performed command is as follows: `selenium.getText("//div[@id='debugState']");`
and the result is the empty String (instead of the contained text). Am I doing something wrong or this is the expected result due to the `style="display:none"`switch.

Comment: Possible duplicate: *[How to gettext() of an element in Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22087952/how-to-gettext-of-an-element-in-selenium-webdriver)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried removing the `style="display:none"` attribute to see what effect it has on your test?  According to [the JavaDoc](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.0/doc/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/DefaultSelenium.html#getText%28java.lang.String%29) this method should do what you need.

Comment: You are right. 
getText
public java.lang.String getText(java.lang.String locator)
Description copied from interface: Selenium
Gets the text of an element. This works for any element that contains text. This command uses either the textContent (Mozilla-like browsers) or the innerText (IE-like browsers) of the element, which is the rendered text shown to the user.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having really hard times trying to get text inside web elements by using the getText() method.
For example if you are trying to retrieve a text in an element after updating it by using:

```
WebElement test = driver.findElement(By.id("idvalue"));
```

when you print the text's content by using the WebElement.getText() API, you'll end up getting the old value contained before updating the field.

What I suggest is accessing the DOM info by executing JScript (in my case I had already included jQuery in the page I was testing with Selenium). Even if the element is hidden, like in your case, you'll get what you need.

```
String test = (String)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return $('#idvalue').text()");
```

p.s. I'm using jQuery text() assuming my idvalue is a DIV element

Comment: Upvote for this because getText will only return data if the element is visible, however sometimes you do want to test the text of a hidden element and the executeScript is the only way to do that.