# How to gettext() of an element in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am finding a textbox by its ID. I need to get the content which is already there inside the text box. For that I am using the `gettext()` method, but it is returning the ID value.

The content in the text box is: *Santhosh*

The output I am getting is = `[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on XP (c0079327-7063-4908-b20a-a606b95830cb)] -> id: ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtName]`

The code is below

#### Code

```
WebElement TxtBoxContent = driver.findElement(By.id(WebelementID));
TxtBoxContent.getText();
System.out.println("Printing " + TxtBoxContent);
```

#### Result

```
Printing [[FirefoxDriver: firefox on XP (c0079327-7063-4908-b20a-a606b95830cb)] -> id: ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtName]
```

Comment: If you add the HTML, we can better help you find the element, and the text.

Comment: Another question asks why (to the solution), but there isn't a proper answer (yet): *[Why is getText() in Selenium not working for <textarea> elements, but getAttribute(“value”) is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379622/selenium-why-is-gettext-not-working-for-textarea-elements-but-getattribute)*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to print the result of the `getText()`. You're currently printing the object `TxtBoxContent`.

`getText()` will only get the inner text of an element.  To get the value, you need to use `getAttribute()`.

```
WebElement TxtBoxContent = driver.findElement(By.id(WebelementID));
System.out.println("Printing " + TxtBoxContent.getAttribute("value"));
```

Comment: i tried your code But it is not returning any text at all it is just showing : Printing  : there is no text after that please help - the text content is in text box i need to fetch the text

Comment: <input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtName" class="textboxnew" type="text" style="width:100%;" onblur="findduplicate(this.value);" maxlength="100" value="Santhosh" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtName"

Comment: i need to fetch the value i.e., Santhosh in it

Comment: Thanks A LOT now its working. Thanks for Saving my Day.... i am new to selenium so bit problem in analyzing the codes

Comment: For Python it would be ...`TxtBoxContent.get_attribute("value")`.

Answer (score 4):

```
text = driver.findElement(By.id('p_id')).getAttribute("innerHTML");
```

Comment: and some explanation

Comment: I could not get the test from the element with the other solutions. This worked for me

Answer (score 4):

You need to store it in a `String` variable first before displaying it like so:

```
String Txt = TxtBoxContent.getText();
System.out.println(Txt);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Python**

```
element.text
```

**Java**

```
element.getText()
```

**C#**

```
element.Text
```

**Ruby**

```
element.text
```