# return Find_element_by_name as a string In Python

Tags: python, string, selenium, selenium-webdriver, return

I need some help form all of you, so I have something like this:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_name("SiteMinderVarForm")
print (element)
```

When I execute the program I receive:

> selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d49d6df9305f2e92eb81aed5c0ed848b", element="0.6436298007036831-4")

And I need a string as result.

I'm trying to automatically login into a web site. If the process of login fails because of an incorrect password or username I need to show a pop up with an error message. So I'm trying to get the name of the form and check if is equal to the actual name. In case it is equal that means the process is successful, and if not the process fails.

If you have any better ideas to do that please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question, it seems like you want the text value contained in the webelement. You can use the webelement.getAttribute("value") method. If you want to get the name attribute of the webelement with name SiteMinderVarForm:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_name("SiteMinderVarForm")
value = element.getAttribute("name")
print(value)
```

Similar to [Using Selenium Web Driver to retrieve value of a HTML input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852287/using-selenium-web-driver-to-retrieve-value-of-a-html-input)
More examples at: [Get Attribute values using Webdriver](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/how-to-get-attribute-values-using-webdriver)

You may also be able to use the webelement.getText() method.

```
element = driver.find_element_by_name("SiteMinderVarForm")
value = element.getText()
print(value)
```

[Difference between getText() and getAttribute()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32307702/difference-b-w-gettext-and-getattribute-in-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: If you wouldn't mind marking this as the correct answer then?