# Extract Text from TD/B HTML tag ,xpath="//table[@class='table']/tbody/tr[1]/td

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am trying to extract the text "2000" and store this in a string from below HTML:

```
<table class="table" _ngcontent-c13="">
    <tbody _ngcontent-c13="">
        <tr _ngcontent-c13="">
            <th _ngcontent-c13="" scope="row">Amount</th>
            <td class="" _ngcontent-c13="">
                <b _ngcontent-c13="">$2000</b>
            </td>  <!-- Added by edit -->
        </tr>      <!-- Added by edit -->
    </tbody>       <!-- Added by edit -->
</table>           <!-- Added by edit -->
```

I am trying below XPath, but it's returning `null`:

```
String text= driver.findelement(by.xpath("xpath="//table[@class='table']/tbody/tr[1]/td")).getAttribute("value")
```

Comment: That code doesn't return null, it won't even compile. Please take a minute to update your question with the actual code you are using.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to `getText()`, not attribute. 
Second, you need text of `<b` element, not `<td`.
You also don't need `xpath=` in xpath
Finally, XPath could be improved:

- eliminated elements you don't care about (such as `tbody`)
- don't use indexes like `tr[1]`, they make xpath easily breakable. Instead use some *meaningful* locators. In this particular case looks like you want to find `<td`, whose `<th` says `Amount`.

So something like this:

```
String text= driver
    .findElement(
        By.xpath("//table[@class='table']//th[text()='Amount']/../td/b"))
    .getText();
```

Answer (score 1):

To match only the text "$2000" you can use this XPath expression:

```
//table[@class='table']/tbody/tr[1]/td/b
```

And to remove the "$", or the first char, use this XPath expression:

```
substring(//table[@class='table']/tbody/tr[1]/td/b,2)
```

To get these values, don't use `.getAttribute("value")`, because the values are no attributes. Try `.getText()` instead. (I also removed the typo of `By` and `findElement`):

```
String text= driver.findElement(By.xpath("substring(//table[@class='table']/tbody/tr[1]/td/b,2)")).getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding the `<b>` element to the xpath? In addition, getAttribute() gets the attribute in the HTML tag, not the value inside the tag. You need the getText() function. Refer to this thread: [Difference b/w getText() and getAttribute() in Selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32307702/difference-b-w-gettext-and-getattribute-in-selenium-webdriver)

TL;DR: Try this:

`String text = driver.findelement(by.xpath("xpath="//table[@class='table']/tbody/tr[1]/td/b")).getText()`

That should return `$2000`, and you can strip the $ easily.