# How to retrieve aria-hidden attribute in Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

```
<h5 class="width-90px text-ellipsis align-center margin-top-bottom-5">
<i class="fa fa-check font-14 " aria-hidden="true">
```

The above one is html for an element.

```
String ok= TickBox.get(3).getAttribute("aria-hidden");
System.out.println(ok);
Assert.assertTrue(TickBox.get(3).getAttribute("aria-hidden") != null);
```

I am using above code to verify, but it returning null.

Comment: What is `TickBox`? how do you locate the element?

Comment: @FindBy(xpath=".//*[@class='width-90px text-ellipsis align-center margin-top-bottom-5']") private List<WebElement> TickBox         @Guy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference b/w getText() and getAttribute() in Selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32307702/difference-b-w-gettext-and-getattribute-in-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: With that locator, you are getting the `H5` element and that element doesn't have the `aria-hidden` attribute, the `I` tag does. Create a locator that finds the `I` tag and then you'll be able to get the attribute.

Comment: h5 class also belongs to same element here, why it is not returning aria-hidden value? @JeffC

Comment: The `H5` element and the `I` element are two different elements. There is no "h5 class" so I'm not sure what you are referring to.

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve the value of the attribute *aria-hidden* you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `cssSelector`:

  ```
  System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("h5.text-ellipsis>i.fa.fa-check.font-14")).getAttribute("aria-hidden"));
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h5[contains(@class,'text-ellipsis')]/i[@class='fa fa-check font-14']")).getAttribute("aria-hidden"));
  ```

Comment: i have to use @FindBy(xpath=".//*[@class='width-90px text-ellipsis align-center margin-top-bottom-5']")
 private List<WebElement> TickBox;                     i am checking a table where few boxes are having tick i.e aria-hidden is true for that, so this xpath is common for all boxes.

Comment: My question is same getAttribute() is not returning aria-hidden value, its returning null.

Comment: @Ash That is because your xpath is too loose and isn't returning the element that you expect. A simple way to do the xpath would be by index. (//i[contains(@class, 'fa-check')])[1]

Answer (score 0):

Try with jquery execution from selenium driver.

Example jquery: 
**$('h5 >i.fa.fa-check').getAttribute('aria-hidden');**

Get the result of attribute

```
String attributeValue = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return $('h5 >i.fa.fa-check').getAttribute('aria-hidden');");
```