# How to get the text from element in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, findby

I am trying to fetch the text ($315.50) from:

```
<td id="balance" class="ng-binding">$315.50</td>
```

I am not succeeding though, I have tried:

```
@FindBy(how = How.CSS, using = "#balance")
private WebElement balance;
```

and

```
@FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "#balance")
private WebElement balance;
```

With these selectors I than do:

```
System.out.println("Balance" + balance)
```

as result I get

```
Balance[[ChromeDriver: chrome on WINDOWS (4ccbccdb5b54de0526e0ec68db88a48c)] -> css selector: #balance]
```

Or if try to do something else with it, I get errors saying that the methods receives an empty string.

For other elements in my test framework I can do manage to fetch the text from elements. The general setup does not seem to be the problem. Anyone an idea what I am doing wrong in this specific example?

Comment: Are you sure, according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32307702/what-is-the-difference-between-gettext-and-getattribute-in-selenium-webdrive one should use getText to find the value between ><. In my example, if I use getAttribute("class") I get "ng-binding" returned, not the dollar value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the HTML:

```
<td id="balance" class="ng-binding">$315.50</td>
```

To identify the element you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *id*:

  ```
  @FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "balance")
  private WebElement balance;
  ```
- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  @FindBy(how = How.CSS, using = "td#balance")
  private WebElement balance;
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  @FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//td[@id='balance']")
  private WebElement balance;
  ```

---

To print the text:

- Using *`getText()`*:

  ```
  System.out.println(balance.getText())
  ```
- Using *`getAttribute("innerHTML")`*:

  ```
  System.out.println(balance.getAttribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using *`getAttribute("innerText")`*:

  ```
  System.out.println(balance.getAttribute("innerText"))
  ```
- Using *`getAttribute("textContent")`*:

  ```
  System.out.println(balance.getAttribute("textContent"))
  ```