# How to use getText and get an attribute in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

Below are separate `textboxt1` IDs for getting the text:

```
WebElement Text = driver.findElement(By.id("incident.number"));
String result = Text.getText();
```

How can I write the code for getting the values from gettext?

Below are `textbox2` id:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("38240a5edb5912000c91d540cf9619b9_text"));
```

I want to get the value from `textbox1` to `textbox2`. How can I get the attributes from getText?

Comment: do you want to pass the value from textbox1 to textbox2? or your gettext result is different then value you are getting.. your question is unclear .. please explain more in detail version

Comment: I want to pass the value from textbox1 to textbox2@shubham jain

Comment: are you able to get the value from textbox1?

Comment: please share HTML code of both textbox1 and textbox2 .. I need to check weather the locator you have mentioned are fine or not

Comment: I have added a answer also may it help you

Comment: Possible duplicate: *[How to gettext() of an element in Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22087952/how-to-gettext-of-an-element-in-selenium-webdriver)*

Answer (score 0):

You can get the string in the textbox by `getAttribute("value")`:

```
String textboxValue = driver.findElement(By.id("38240a5edb5912000c91d540cf9619b9_text")).getAttribute("value");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to get the value from the textbox, then just pass that string to textbox2 using `sendKeys` as below.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("38240a5edb5912000c91d540cf9619b9_text")).sendKeys(result);
```

I am supposing that the locator is fine and able to locate the elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the the value of text box using getAttribute("value") like driver.findElement(By.id("38240a5edb5912000c91d540cf9619b9_text")).getAttribute("value"). This will return you the value of a textbox.