# Selenium WebDriver get text from input field

Tags: selenium

I'm writing a test to assert the default text value within an `<input>` tag. However, it's not playing ball:

```
Assert.assertThat(webDriver.findElement(By.id("inputTag")).getText(), Matchers.is("2"));
```

Comment: I suspect `<getAttribute()>` given the correct attribute might do the trick but I'm not sure what that is.

Comment: Possible duplicate: *[How to gettext() of an element in Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22087952/how-to-gettext-of-an-element-in-selenium-webdriver)*

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This is the `input` element - you need to get the `value` attribute:

```
webDriver.findElement(By.id("inputTag")).getAttribute("value")
```

Comment: in python(3) it's called `get_attribute`.

Comment: It seems that the `"value"` attribute does not always get updated when the user makes changes. Since `getText()` doesn't work, what would you suggest in this situation?

Answer (score 2):

The most reliable solution I found, is executing a JavaScript script and return the value attribute of the [HTMLInputElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) from JavaScript.

I have tested this in several ways and the value was always correct, even after changing the input field value.

#### PHP

```php
$input = $driver->findElement( WebDriverBy::id( 'inputTag' ) );
$value = $driver->executeScript( 'return arguments[0].value', $input );
```

```php
// A custom PHP function that returns the value of an input field:
function getValue(RemoteWebDriver $driver, WebDriverBy $by ) {
    return $driver->executeScript( 
        'return arguments[0].value', 
        $driver->findElement( $by ) 
    );
}

// Sample usage:
$value = getValue( $driver, WebDriverBy::id( 'inputTag' ) );
```

#### Java

```java
//driver being your WebDriver
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;  

WebElement inpElement = driver.findElement(By.id("inputTag"));
String text = (String) js.executeScript("return arguments[0].value", inpElement);
```

#### Python 3

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
input_element = driver.findElement(By.ID, "inputTag")
value = input_element.execute_script("return arguments[0].value", input_element)
```