# Unable to get text from input element in selenium

Tags: java, html, spring, selenium

Using Java/Spring Tags i wrote a html file having some radio buttons which are getting from DataBase. Now i am writing Selenium test case to click that radio button. As I'am using excel sheet to read values, my Radio button values are there in Excel sheet. So how can I identify Radio buttons using text in excel and click it from Selenium WebDriver.

I have Tried Using Xpath and looping through WebElement and used getText() method still iam getting empty Text.

### Actual Html:

```
<html>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 prop_value">
<c:forEach items="${products}" var="productTemp">
<form:radiobutton style="margin-left : 30px"                             
path="${mtool.productDetail.productId}" class="radiobtn"                                             
name="product" value="${productTemp.productId}"/>${productTemp.productName} 
</c:forEach></div>
</html>
```

now When i inspect this in Browser This Html was generated as below

### Inspected Html:

```
<div class="col-xs-8 col-md-8 prop_title">
Product<span class="required">*</span>
<input id="1" name="product" style="margin-left : 30px" class="radiobtn" 
type="radio" value="1">CAR
<input id="2" name="product" style="margin-left : 30px" class="radiobtn" 
type="radio" value="2">BUS
<input id="3" name="product" style="margin-left : 30px" class="radiobtn" 
type="radio" value="3">TRUCK
<input id="4" name="product" style="margin-left : 30px" class="radiobtn" 
type="radio" value="4">TRAIN
<input id="5" name="product" style="margin-left : 30px" class="radiobtn" 
type="radio" value="5">AEROPLANE
</div>
```

These values CAR,BUS,TRUCK,TRAIN,AEROPLANE are stored in an excel sheet.Now to click the radio button based on the value stored in Excel sheet I wrote Selenium Code as Below.

### Example.java

```
for(int i=0; i<totalRows; i++){
        cell = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(0);
        System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='col-xs-6 col-md-6 prop_value']")).getText());
        List<WebElement> elmnt=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@name='product' and @class='radiobtn']/following-sibling::text()/parent::div/input"));
        for(WebElement list : elmnt){

            String text=list.getText();
            System.out.println("Text"+text);
            if(text.equalsIgnoreCase(cell.getStringCellValue())){
                list.click();
            }
        }
```

It was Just a code respective to only radio buttons, so I did not write a complete class. Now I'am getting empty Text so radio button was not getting clicked. So someone can let me know how to do this. Thank You

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36202689/selenium-webdriver-get-text-from-input-field
works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you requested I am posting another answer with cell.

```
for(int j=0; j<totalRows; j++){
         cell = sheet.getRow(j).getCell(0); 
        //Radio Button element 
         List<WebElement> elmnt = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[text()[contains(.,'')]]/input"));
         //It returns Entire Div Text  
         String[] parts =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='product']/parent::div")).getText().split(" ");

         for (int i=1;i<parts.length;i++)
             {
                    System.out.println(parts[i]);
                    //Verifying cell value here.
                    if(parts[i].trim().equalsIgnoreCase(cell.getStringCellValue()))
                    {
                        elmnt.get(i-1).click();
                    }

              }

         }
```

Please let me know that is what you looking after?

Answer (score 0):

Use this xpath:
`List<WebElement> elmnt=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@name='product']"));`

Comment: already used this xpath still iam not getting text.Because if you see there are no closing tag for <input>.But it is dynamically Generated

Comment: Ohh sorry i missed that, use can use * instead of `input` then. That might help

Comment: It seems to be not working.Again same empty Text was being printed

Comment: Ohhh.. but your use case is that you are picking the value from the excel and then clicking that text on your webpage, right ? So you can directly go to the text xpath using `String productName=cell.getStringCellValue()` and `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()="+productName+"]")).click();` ,you can get the productName from your excel sheet. Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: when iam trying to find element in browser using //*[text()="CAR"].Then iam not able to find element as there are some spaces in the text.

Comment: If there are spaces when you are getting the value from excel then you can use trim() to remove the extra spaces and if there are spaces on the webpage div then i guess the spaces would be constant, so you can add the static number of spaces after your text as well.

Comment: no in webpage only there are some spaces so when i search the element in webpage using xpath,it was not able to locate.Now i cannot add the spaces in excel sheet right.So is there any other way to do this

Comment: Ok, so you can use contains in the xpath instead of equating the whole text like: `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),"+productName+")]")).click()` Let me know if this works

Answer (score 0):

You may try with innerText:

```
String text=list.getAttribute("innerText");
```

Comment: I tried this but there were some spaces in text it seems so when i print the text it was printing empty

Comment: Do you mean to say, text are retrieving with spaces ? Or only spaces are retrived ?

Comment: Ok if you see in list it was showing 5 elements.So my variable list has 5 elements.But when iam doing list.getText() it was printing empty characters

Comment: If it not required that every time HTML do retrieve getText, And if so we have to use alternatives like innerText()

Answer (score 0):

You can do it other way.If you wish to do that.It will give you entire 'div' text value.Then you can split this value and compare with your excel shell value.

```
//Radio Button element 
List<WebElement> elmnt = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[text()[contains(.,'')]]/input"));
//It returns Entire Div Text  
String[] parts =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='product']/parent::div")).getText().split(" ");

for (int i=1;i<parts.length;i++)
    {
          System.out.println(parts[i]);
           elmnt.get(i-1).click();
           Thread.sleep(2000); //sleep i have used for testing purpose not required in real scenario.
    }
```

Comment: Fine now iam able to get Text it seems to be working Thank You.But in for loop you were iterating each element and clicking on it.But my case is all the values will be stored in excel sheet so if value in excel is CAR,then CAR radio button should be clicked.So Help me with this

Comment: Ok I am posting another answer to help you out.Please accept my code if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can get input using xpath below, but better to ask developers to add close tags:

```
//node()[normalize-space(.)='CAR']/preceding::input[1]

//node()[normalize-space(.)='AEROPLANE']/preceding::input[1]
```