# Unable to convert a string value from a web element to double

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to convert a String from a webelement into an integer.

However, I'm getting following error in `parseInt`

[image]

```
public String getLoanAmount() {
    return loanAmount.getText();
    int i = Integer.parseInt(driver.findElement(By.id("00N28000001bbuD_ileinner"))).getText();
    double d = i;
    if ((d < 15000) || (d > 35000)) {
        System.out.println("Error: Loan Amount should not be NULL and should be between 5000 to 35000 AUD.");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Entered value in the Loan Amount field is within appropriate range.");
    }
}
```

Can anyone assist on this issue? First of all is this possible? and are the steps correct to achieve it?

Comment: The error message is clear: you are trying to convert a string which into an integer and it can't be done, most likely because the string is not a representation of a number.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen where do you get that from?

Answer (score 1):

You can only have a String as an argument for that parse method.  I am assuming `.getText()` gets a string, and if so you have your parentheses wrong.  Try this instead.  Notice the placement of the parentheses.

```
int i = Integer.parseInt(driver.findElement(By.id("00N28000001bbuD_ileinner")).getText());
```

Answer (score 1):

First line or your method is `return` which means nothing after it would ever run. Once you solve that change the following line

```
int i = Integer.parseInt(driver.findElement(By.id("00N28000001bbuD_ileinner"))).getText();
```

To

```
int i = Integer.parseInt(driver.findElement(By.id("00N28000001bbuD_ileinner")).getText());
```

notice bracket placement is after getText() instead of before

Comment: Thank you all for the inputs. The issue was fixed by placing the return after processing the if loop and correcting the bracket placement after getText()

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems with your code:

**Issue 1**

First line of method `getLoanAmount()` is:

```
return loanAmount.getText();
```

Method will return the value at that line. So, any line below the `return` statement wont be executed.

**Issue 2**

`Integer.parseInt(String)` is expecting an `String` argument... Not an `WebElement`

So, you can not directly pass the `WebElement` to `Integer.parseInt(String)`

First, you have to get the String from the WebElement.

Based on [THIS ASNWER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22088131/4860513) you must do:

```
WebElement webElem = driver.findElement(By.id("00N28000001bbuD_ileinner"));
int i = Integer.parseInt(webElem.getAttribute("value"));
```

**OR**

```
WebElement webElem = driver.findElement(By.id("00N28000001bbuD_ileinner"));
int i = Integer.parseInt(webElem.getText());
```