# Get the text present inside the span in selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have to get the value inside the span tag,How to get the value?Class name is same but when there is an error in any of the field for that class the text will be visible .For example i have twofields :
1)depositorname
2)company name
If company name is wrong,Then message is "Company name not found".This message is displayed in span tag were depositorname span tag doesnot have linktext value.
[sameclass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRTNr.png)

Comment: Is this not what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/a/22088131/1955559

Comment: @Bharath Can you consider to showcase your work please? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need just to configure a situation when that span is visible. Find this span and make getText operation.