# How can I get text of an element in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, gettext

How can I get text of an element in Selenium WebDriver?

I'm trying the Text() method, but it's not returning text. I have tried getting the Attribute using "value" as well, but again it's not working and returning a "null" value.

How can I get the text of the selected element?

#### Screenshot

[image: Click on link for screenshot reference]

Comment: selenium web driver in what language ??? selenium for java, or etc...??

Comment: I am using language as java

Comment: can you upload your java source. so can have a look..

Comment: Possible duplicate: *[How to gettext() of an element in Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22087952/how-to-gettext-of-an-element-in-selenium-webdriver)*

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50732816/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Let’s presume you have to get the text inside a paragraph, like so:

```
// Initialize browser
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setHeadless(false);

// Create a new instance of the Chrome driver
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

// Launch the Online Store Website
driver.get("file://" + YOUR_PATH_TO_HTML_FILE);

// You get all the paragraph as a list of WebElements
List<WebElement> paras = driver.findElements(By.tagName("p"));

// Then iterate
for (WebElement para : paras) {

    // You can get text inside as this
    System.out.println(para.getText());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I am able to find that particular element by unique Xpath, and from that Xpath I am trying .getText() method, that is not returning text.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```html
<div id="response" class="clearFix">

<div class="clearFix paddingT10 paddingB10">
<span class="flL transaction_rejected transaction_icon">X</span>
    <span class="flL transaction_htext">Transaction Rejected</span>
</div>
    <div id="responseCustom">
        <div style="margin-bottom: 10px;" class="portlet ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all"><div class="portlet-header headercolor ui-state-default ui-corner-all dblclickbound mousedownbound"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick flR"></span>Messages</div><div class="portlet-content contentcolor"><table width="50%"><tbody><tr></tr><tr><td><b>Host Reply Message:</b></td><td>ERR000 BOX NOT CLOSED</td></tr></tbody></table></div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flL paddingT15 paddingB10 width99_percent">
        <input type="button" class="btn_sty marginB10 ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" id="btnReSubmit" style="display:none" onclick="validateTranData(); return false" value="ReSubmit" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. What have you posted? What is the intent? Shouldn't it be in the question? You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50732816/edit).